# Group data with duplicate values into one cell in excel

Tags: database, excel, merge, duplicates, cells

I am trying to figure out how to combine all of the data affiliated with duplicate values into one cell.  For example

```
Variant Group    Variant
101               XS
101               S
101               M
102               Red
102               Blue
102               Green
```

I'd like to create a worksheet where all of the variants are combined into one cell from the same variant group.  For example, I would have a worksheet that looked like this

```
Variant Group   Variant
101             XS, S, M
102             Red, Blue Green
```

Can anyone suggest how to do that easily?  Thanks!

Comment: welcome to SO :) Can you post the attempts you've made at trying to accomplish this? See [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to receive the most beneficial help from SO.

Comment: I'd say your only way is to go with VBA.  This is fairly simple to accomplish, though.